# checking when function starts and ends in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to follow after a function in a program.
How can I know when a specific function starts, and when is it just about to end? (or just have ended)

I have the function's start address and can check all the registers

Comment: In a simple program, a subroutine ends at one or more [`ret`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret)s, depending on the program flow.

Comment: Usually, compiled code will contain one function start to finish, but more generally, i.e. with assembly code, there's no requirement that one function is separate from another — two or more functions can intertwine.  There's the static start and end of function code, and then there's the dynamic start and end, where early returns can leave the function at arbitrary points.  In assembly, one function can have multiple exit points, let alone multiple entry points.

Comment: @zx485: But not all programs are *that* simple.  It's not rare for a function to end with a `jmp` tailcall to another function.  And tail-duplication optimization is also common, so there can be multiple paths out of a function (multiple `ret` instructions to set breakpoints on.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to know, how internally a function works, you should use a debugger in your platform. for example, if you are using the Windows operating system, you can use Windbg and IDA Pro to debug a function. If you are using Linux/Unix-based operating systems, you can use gdb debugger, hopper, and radare2. For example, To determine when a specific function starts and ends, you can follow the steps mentioned in the following section to achieve this with Windbg:

1. Attach the process to the Windbg debugger or open the program with it.
2. Set a breakpoint at the start address of the function you're
   interested in. For example bp main.
3. Run the program using the g command to continue
   execution until the breakpoint is hit.
4. Once the breakpoint is hit, you can examine the current state of the
   program, including the register values using the r command. This
   will show you the values of the processor registers.
5. Step through the function using the p command to execute one
   instruction at a time. This will allow you to observe the changes in
   register values and memory as the function executes.

   You can set another breakpoint at the end of the function if you want to stop execution there as well. Use the bp command with the end address of the function.
6. Continue stepping through the function until you reach the end and
   see ret instruction in order to return to the caller stack frame.

By setting breakpoints at the start and end addresses of the function in the debuggers, and stepping through the instructions, you can track the execution flow and observe the changes in register values.

Comment: As you said bruh, it looks like. Nowadays everything looks like produced by chatgpt but I write it by myself because debugging with windbg isn't difficult which I wanted the help of AI.

Comment: Yes I agree - I think in this case I probably misidentified it. I'll delete my comment. Sorry

Comment: I was looking for the end address of the function. It's for a task where I need to count all the times the function was used, excluding recursion. I had the start address of the function and wanted to know the end address. In the end, the moment the function started, I saved the rsp as a returnaddress and then checked step by step until the rip  was equal to the return address. Worked well enough for me.
I used a debugger in c but run it on linux emulator

Comment: @aboi: You mean you saved the qword RSP was pointing to?  Most programs will never have RIP equal to a value that RSP has or had, since they have non-executable stacks.  Anyway, yes, looking for RIP = return address is one way, but it makes `jmp` tailcalls count as part of the function.